# How to add a button with image and text dynamically in Android GridView?

Tags: android, image, gridview, dynamic, button

I want to add `ImageButtons` with text dynamically to a `GridView` (Something like below) and also set a `listener` such that a user enter a different page, when he clicks on an icon. The buttons will need to fill up horizontally first so I think I will need 2 loops. I have searched but I can't find a good tutorial on how to do this.

[image: Image buttons in GridView]
<sub>(source: [botskool.com](https://www.botskool.com/sites/default/files/image/sudoku5.jpg))</sub>

How I intend to do it

```
ArrayList<String> options = getOptions();

for(int i=0; i<options.size(); i++){
    String opt = options.get(i);
    if(opt.equals("Contacts")){
        //Add Contacts button with image in GridView
        Button btn = new Button(this); 
        //Set button text
        //Set image
        //Set listener to go to another activity
        layout.addView(btn); 
    }else if(..){
        //Add another button with image in GridView
        //Set button text
        //Set image
        //Set listener to go to another activity
    }

}
```

I would really appreciate if someone can guide me on how to set `ButtonImage`, `Button Text` and `listener` all together dynamically in a `GridView`. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Create xml file and take Gridview in it and even Textview
reference it in the class/java file you wnat to use

Now when you use the grid view you will use the imageadapter  and extends  the base adapter
while in that you will have the getview() function where u set the image source dynamically and even set the Textview every time